# How do I specify which version of the app I want to use in settings' INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, settings

I've got a version of a module (South 0.6) installed system-wise and a newer version installed in my home. When I add 'south' to my INSTALLED_APPS, it uses the system-wise version. How can I tell Django to use the version in my home?

Thanks

Jul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (and [virtualenvwraper](http://www.doughellmann.com/projects/virtualenvwrapper/)) is definitely your friend for handling things like this when you are able to create a new environment.  You should go ahead and play with it.  If you are not able to mess around with virtualenv right now, you can just put your personal python lib path at the front of PYTHONPATH:

```
# from your command prompt:
$ export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/your/python/libs:$PYTHONPATH
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a package named [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) which was designed to handle this specific problem.  It allows you to create a virtual environment for each python project (ie. Django project), letting you choose which version of a module is installed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you know if I can use it for an existing project?